# Unity Reference Properties Are Not Saved Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, alias, openai-api

I am currently working on a Unity 2D game project (version 2022.2.6f1) where I'm trying to integrate the OpenAI GPT-3 API using an C#/.NET wrapper library, version 1.6 https://github.com/OkGoDoIt/OpenAI-API-dotnet. I get the error that the type 'IAsyncEnumerable' exists in both 'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263' and 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

I am able to solve this in Visual Studio by adding an alias to System.Interactive.Async, I rebuild and all of the errors dissapear. However, I go into Unity afterwards, the errors are still there, when I double click them I am sent back to VS where I can see the change I made was reverted, the alias for System.Interactive.Async is back to global and I am back to the same errors.

Is there any way to keep those changes even after exiting VS? I have the same issue with .csproj file.

Comment: Maybe the solution from this thread will help. [Type exists in 2 assemblies](https://forum.unity.com/threads/type-task-exists-in-both-unity-tasks-and-mscorelib.855385/)

Comment: @hijinxbassist it truly did, I needed to install it from Unity rather than taking it from GitHub. So I installed NuGet from Unity and got the OpenAI API from there. Thank you very much, this was killing me for days haha